# Json not enabled for current project

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an issue with the PARSE_JSON function in google big query when trying to convert a string formatted json into a json format.

SELECT PARSE_JSON(data) FROM table

Error received : "Json not enabled for current project"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Parsing JSON is already possible, if a single value is extraced from a JSON:

```
Select JSON_VALUE(PARSE_JSON(data).A)  FROM
(
Select '{"A":5,"B":12}' as data
)
```

For using `PARSE_JSON` and store the result in table field, you need to enroll in the preview (March 2022), apply here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data

Comment: I showed both routes: extract only one value from a JSON string AND how to enroll and enable the JSON preview feature. Please write why the only answer to this question is bad.